# find the common ratio of geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of first $3$ terms of a geometric series is $39$. If $t_1=27$ ,what is the common ratio? look for all possible answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $27$ is the first term, then the other two terms are $27r$ and $27r^2$, where $r$ is the common ratio. In this case, we have $27 + 27r + 27r^2= 39$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried that but I cant get r

Comment: Now, we have $27r^2 + 27r - 12 = 0$. If you solve this for $r$ by factoring or with the quadratic formula, you get $r = 1/3$ or $r = -4/3$.

Comment: oh yea that is it, thank you :)